# Stibo STEP - finding product secondary hierarchy using JS SDK

Tags: master-data-management

At STIBO STEP, writing a global business rule, using javascript SDK, I wanna see which secondary hierarchy a product is at.

example if was primary hierarchy, it would be node.getParent().

The "node" is a "com.stibo.core.domain.impl.FrontProductImpl".

The secondary hierarchy is a reference of "Product To Classification Link type".

So which method could be used to retrieve the secondary hirarchy?